# Error de ejecución ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

En mi aplicación aparece el siguiente error:

> (System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: 'HTTP no pudo
>   registrar la dirección URL
>   http://+:7744/EngineCommands/EngineCommands/. El proceso no tiene
>   derechos de acceso a este espacio de nombres (consulte
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70)

alguien sabe a que se debe?

Comment: Prueba a ejecutarlo como administrador

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: Funciono. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Traduzco libremente [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22687767/579895)</sub>:

El problema es que hacer un bind a un puerto tcp requiere privilegios administrativos. Hay un par de maneras de lidiar con ello.

1. Mantén abierto una ventana de comandos de administrador. Así puedes ejecutar tu programa directamente.
2. Ejecuta VS como administrador.
3. Crea un archivo de manifiesto de aplicación, especificando `requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"`.